# Elementary OS Black screen after driver update?

Tags: release-freya, boot, graphic-drivers, system, display

I installed a graphics driver update using NeteXt'73 and now my screen goes permanently black soon after the pulsating elementary logo boot animation. How can I fix this? I cannot login nor access the terminal. I am running on a Lenovo Y50 with a NVIDIA® GeForce™ GTX 860M.

**Update**: I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450046/black-screen-with-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) but I can't uninstall the drivers when booting into recovery because it says everything is "read-only".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, read only?
That would require an read/write remount:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/<your parition identifier> /
```

You can find your parition identifier by using:

```
mount -v | grep "^/" | awk '{print "\nPartition identifier: " $1  "\n Mountpoint: "  $3}'
```

exactly as SirCharlo wrote here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write